# Working with GOOGLE Analytics API - Metrics/Dimensions

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

Currently, I'm trying to work with Google Analytics API with no success as always finished with an error - **"Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together."**

As an assumption should be easy to fix and check the metrics and dimensions, but even if I use the [DEVELOPMENT TOOL](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#mode=api&cats=ecommerce) it still shows this error.

**PYTHON CODE:**

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import json 


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'key.json'
VIEW_ID = 'REPORT_ID'



def initialize_analyticsreporting():

  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

  # Build the service object.
  analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

  return analytics


def get_report(analytics):

  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'dateRanges': 
          [
            {'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}
          ],

          'metrics': [
            {'expression': 'ga:transactions'},
          ],
          'dimensions': 
          [
            {'name': 'ga:productName'}
          ]
        }]
      }
  ).execute()


def main():
  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  response = get_report(analytics)
  with open('analytics_data.json', "w+") as op:
    op.write(json.dumps(response))  

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

As an example, if use metrics/dimensions based [Google Python Example Code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py)

```
      'metrics': [
        {'expression': 'sessions'},
      ],
      'dimensions': 
      [
        {'name': 'ga:country'}
      ]
```

It returns with the appropriate result, but if I need `ga:transactions`and`ga:productName` it returns with the error above.

**IDEA:**
Can assume that maybe even with correct View_ID (Report ID) it still do not connect to appropriate report ??

**Could anyone help with this?**

Answer (score 2):

I think the error message you get is correct as it is. You are simply trying to get an unallowed combination of metrics and dimensions. You can try it in the [Google Analytics Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/), and you will get the same result.

Using your query settings with a working view ID:
[image]

If you'd like to see the number of transactions, that contained at least of your products, I suggest to use Unique Purchase as a metric (ga:uniquePurchases). Although my test view has no ecommerce data, you can see, that the query has run successfully:
[image]

You can check this query in your own view using this [Query Explorer setting link](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=7daysAgo&end-date=today&metrics=ga%3AuniquePurchases&dimensions=ga%3AproductName).

Comment: Have a look: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

Comment: Could you please specify, what should I look exactly? Thanks.

Comment: What you do, is you select productName and dimension, and the transaction, this website will tell you, will you allow to use these parameters together or not.

Comment: OK, I got your point. Still, if you open Analytics UI and try to build a custom report, you'll end up with the same result. You won't be able to build a report with this dimension-metric combination: https://i.imgur.com/R2gRZW0.png Is there a reason, why Unique Purchase metrics is not suitable for your case?